# Replay downloaded log files into an ELK server

Tags: logging, log4j, elastic-stack

Our deployed systems collect "regular" plain old log4j log files.  Since it is a distributed system, there are 5-10 of these.  When there is a problem it is possible to obtain the log files as a zip file.

I found [this docker ELK image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQwIPq6sfWAhVF5iYKHcCxAUkQFghKMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Felk-docker.readthedocs.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNHKHyjpB7Y-2kfWWOLaWT01t7EQlA) which works great.  However, this is new to me, and all the examples talk about using something such as `filebeat` to play the log information to ElasticSearch.  I am wondering if there exists a way to essentially "replay" an existing set of log files into such an ELK container instance?  Or is this something I would need to build?

Comment: By replay you mean inserting the logs in ELK or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  The deployed systems won't (at least initially) have an ELK server, but will collect a set of log files that can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you don't want to use filebeat as it handles network outage gracefully and guarantees log delivery. I would use filebeat even if it is just a local installation (same domain where ELK is) and i would just feed the collected logs to it from your system (with rsync or manually) if you don't want to install filebeat on every log source server to send to your main logstash instance.

On the other hand there is a very basic logstash file input plugin which you can use for direct reading: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html

Comment: The reason I didn't accept or give this answer the bounty is because I believe that I stated why i could not use filebeat AND that it is not a local installation!  However, if I receive a set of log files from say a customer, and you are saying that filebeat could be used to "replay" those into ELK, that WOULD be an answer, but I would need to know HOW to do that!

Comment: you did not explain why you don't want to use filebeat...it can read log files matching a pattern so if your new files abide to the rule they will be parsed. It is irrelevant if the files are created manually or automatically just make sure to put a timestamp in the filenames so they are distinguished easily (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/how-filebeat-works.html). Also I gave you a second option which is not filebeat but direct log parsing.